# Is it possible to download files like PDF with HttpClient?

Tags: java, pdf, httpurlconnection, apache-commons-httpclient

I found some examples here on how to download a file but most of them seem to be using HttpURLConnection. is it possible to download files with HttpClient?

Comment: "Yes". It's all just HTTP GET requests.

Comment: (Once an HttpResponse is obtained, after an "execute", the HttpEntity, which has a stream that can be read from, is accessible. [See the API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) which provides a trivial example of just this).

Comment: I would prefer to Jsoup instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using httpclient is pretty easy.  Here's a link to it's tutorial.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e43

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urltofetch);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    long len = entity.getContentLength();
    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
    // write the file to whether you want it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do with `HttpURLConnection` you can do, usually better, with `HttpClient` look through their examples about file transfer and you will see how.